# Generate odom from command velocity

Tags: navigation, odometry

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I modified a RC car (a big one) for driving it. Nowadays I made my own controller for sending the data to the car so now I'm able to teleoperate it and I have mounted on it a kinect so now I'm able to receive the image from it.

Right now I want to navigate with it using AMCL (I already have a map made with the turtlebot) but the problem is that I don't have any odometry so I'm thinking about generate my own one transforming the cmd_vel into odom msg

I don't have any idea about where I should start from. Do you have any idea?

Thanks you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222294/generate-odom-from-command-velocity/) by [solosito](https://answers.ros.org/users/25128/solosito/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2015-12-10

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [solosito](https://answers.ros.org/users/25128/solosito/) on 2015-12-10**:
Yes, I already knew that, but at the moment is the only way that I have for doing it. Anyway, thank you for your help, I'm gonna continue looking into it.

**Comment by [mkhansen](https://answers.ros.org/users/25277/mkhansen/) on 2015-12-10**:
Look at the "Hector SLAM" package, that allows you to do visual odometry and navigation

**Comment by [sal](https://answers.ros.org/users/89022/sal/) on 2022-04-01**:
were you able to find a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are able to send commands, you can use the commands [to create your odometry](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/Odom). Although, in this way you do not consider dynamic of your system. Hopefully amcl compensate for it...

---

Originally posted by [mohsen1989m](https://answers.ros.org/users/22803/mohsen1989m/) with karma: 397 on 2015-12-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0